# ¿Como imprimir solo el primer elemento de un arreglo while?

Tags: javascript, html, while, blade

estoy imprimiendo un arreglo pero quiero que imprima solo el primer elemento, creo que la solución esta en el contador del bucle, pero no estoy seguro como hacer para que en lugar de recorrer todos los registros, solo recorra el primer elemento y lo imprima . Este es mi código:
Saludos

```js
calendario=$("#date-in").val();
 let calendario1 = document.getElementsByClassName("date-in1");
var i=0;  
while(i<calendario1.length){
 if(calendario!="" && calendario!=calendario1[0].value){
 //En la sig tabla es donde voy a imprimir el primer elemento del arreglo 
        var fila ='<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td ALIGN="center"><button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onClick="eliminar('+cont+');"></button></td><td><input type="text" id="date-in" name="calendario[]" value="'+calendario+'" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
        cont++;
        evaluar();
        $('#detalles').append(fila);
      }

    else
    {  
      alert("No puedes agregar ");  
    }
   i++; 
}
```

```html
<input type ="date" class="form-control" name="date-in" id="date-in">
@foreach($holi as $hol)
                     
<input type="date" name="date_in1" class="date-in1" id="date-in1" value="{{$hol->holiday}}" >
                       
@endforeach
```

Comment: tienes una variable i que es como tu contador puedes hacer `if(i == 0){ //codigo es el primer elemento}`

Comment: Puedes poner `break;` para salir luego de la primera iteracción. Aunque no le encuentro sentido a tu proceder desde un punto de vista lógico. ¿Por qué quieres detenerlo?

Comment: Si solo quieres imprimr el primer elemento, en vez de utilizar el `calendario1.length` podrías hacer `while(i<1){ i++ }` y con eso solo te ejecutaría el bucle una única vez.

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido utilizar un bucle para coger el primer elemento cuando lo puedes hacer directamente sin iterar.

Comment: Es que como es una tabla que se va agregando manualmente con un boton registro por registro. si pongo el if(i==0) y el while(i<1) solo me funciona una vez mi validación del if, y no entiendo porque.

Answer (score 2):

No hay necesidad de usar un while ya que no hay una iteracion. En este caso solo necesitas acceder a un elemento en un index especifico.

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
calendario=$("#date-in").val();
//Obtenemos el arreglo de objetos.
let calendario1 = document.getElementsByClassName("date-in1");

//Siempre verificar que dicho arreglo tenga una longitud mayor a 0.
if(calendario1.length>0){
  var primer_valor = calendario1[0]; // Objeto en la primer posición. 
  // Resto de de codigo...
}
```

Recuerda siempre verificar que el arreglo contenga objetos. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres imprimir o obtener el primer valor de tu arreglo vasta con que coloques

`var primer_valor = calendario1[0];`

y la variable llamada primer_valor contiene el valor que estas buscando para que la utilices donde quieras... **Quita el While** ya que no lo necesitas para lo que quieres hacer, saludos.

Comment: si necesito el while para recorrer el arreglo y hacer la validacion del if y una vez que se haya cumplido imprimir en la tabla el elemento del input calendario

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví aunque no me gusta como quedo porque si quiero comparar con muchos elementos tendría que agregar en el if desde [1][2][3] hasta n elementos de forma manual. Lo que hice fue que con su ayuda puse el while(i<1) y dentro del if me quedaría así para que me haga correctamente la validación.

```js
if(calendario!="" && calendario!=calendario1[0].value  && calendario!=calendario1[1].value && calendario!=calendario[2])
```